# Clojure get the value inside a map

Tags: clojure, hashmap

How do I get openid.claimed_id or any other field in a map like this?

:openid.claimed_id won't work.

```
{"openid.response_nonce" "2015-07-25T09:31:45ZXrcrR0Lk35St5ESZQ0tg40PbBXU=", "openid.identity" "http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/xxx", "openid.ns" "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0", "openid.op_endpoint" "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login", "openid.mode" "id_res", "openid.sig" "zuiyNzf/QLP9Ci/czElIo1Z3nE0=", "openid.signed" "signed,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle", "openid.assoc_handle" "1234567890", "openid.claimed_id" "http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/xxx", "openid.return_to" "http://localhost:3000/resp"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys in your map are Strings and not Keywords.

You can either use:

```
(get m "openid.claimed_id")
```

or you can first convert the String keys to Keywords and then lookup based on a Keyword:

```
(:openid.claimed_id (clojure.walk/keywordize-keys m))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since a map is also a function that can do lookup on itself, the simplest way to do this is

```
(m "openid.claimed_id")
```

with `m` being your map.